# How to set proxy to ActiveMQConnectionFactory to send messages

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

I am using spring activemq for sending jms messages to activemq message queue.
The messagequeue is created on a remote server.I have to set a proxy to reach to that message queue server from my local machine.

Can anyone help me on how to add proxy to activemqConnectionFactory class.

I tried using `HttpClientTransport`, `ProxyConnector`, `NetworkConnector` classes where I set the broker URL, but I am not sure how to add those to the `activemqconnectionFactory`.

Please find the details below:

```
message.queue.broker.url=ssl://<HOSTNAME>:61617

HttpClientTransport httpClientTransport = new HttpClientTransport(null, new URI(brokerUrl));
httpClientTransport.setProxyHost("<proxyHost>");
httpClientTransport.setProxyPort(3128);
httpClientTransport.start();

ProxyConnector proxy = new ProxyConnector();
proxy.setBind(new URI(brokerUrl));
proxy.setRemote(new URI(brokerUrl));
proxy.start();

NetworkConnector netConnector = new NetworkConnector() {
};
netConnector.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
netConnector.start();


ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionfactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(userName, password, brokerUrl);

CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionfactory);
cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(50);

ActiveMQQueue activeMqQueue = new ActiveMQQueue(destination);

jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(sslConnectionFactory);
jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(activeMqQueue);

@Override
public void sendMessage(final String text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            Message message = session.createTextMessage(text);
            return message;
        }
    });
}
```

When I run the above code, I get ConnectionTimedOutException:

> Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: ssl://:61617. Reason: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

I also tried with

```
ssl://<URL>?transport.proxyHost=<PROXYHOST>amp;transport.proxyPort=3128
```

Thanks in Advance.